# How to rotate a lattice points about an arbitrary axis

Tags: computational-geometry, rotation

I have

```
hexpoints = 
  Table[{Cos[n Pi/3] + 1, Sin[n Pi/3] + \[Sqrt]3/2}, {n, 6}];
```

Which gives the fundamental cell to be applied in

```
ptss[x_, y_] := 
 Flatten[Table[{{3 m, \[Sqrt]3 n}, {3 m + 
      3/2, \[Sqrt]3 n + \[Sqrt]3/2}}, {m, 0, x}, {n, 0, y}], 2]
```

by a transformation

```
hexlattice = 
  TranslationTransform[# - hexpoints[[1]]][hexpoints] & /@ ptss[1, 1];
```

In this case is a set of points

```
{{{0, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-(3/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {-1, -Sqrt[3]}, {0, -Sqrt[3]}, ...
```

ListPlot of them

[image]

How could I rotate these points, by an arbitrary axis and angle?

Comment: Have you had a chance to check out `RotationTransform`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to use that, but with no success (in hexpointss = 
 Table[{Cos[n Pi/3] + 1, Sin[n Pi/3] + \[Sqrt]3/2}, {n, 6}])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
hexlattice = Join @@ (TranslationTransform[# - hexpoints[[1]]][hexpoints] & /@ ptss[1, 1]);

Manipulate[Graphics[{Gray, PointSize[Medium], Point[hexlattice],
    Red, Rotate[Point @ #, θ, x] & /@ hexlattice}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, GridLines -> (List /@ x)], 
 {θ, 0, 2 Pi, Experimental`AngularSlider[##] &}, 
 {{x, {0, 0}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Using `Graph` to connect points to their translations:

```
ClearAll[colors]
colors[t_, x_][p_] := p /. Thread[Range[2 Length @ hexlattice] -> 
 Join[#, #] & @(ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[Range[Length @ hexlattice]])];

Manipulate[Graph[DirectedEdge[#, # + Length @ hexlattice] & /@ Range[Length @ hexlattice], 
    VertexSize -> {_ -> Scaled[.02], 
     (Alternatives @@ Range[Length @ hexlattice]) -> Scaled[.015]}, 
    EdgeStyle -> {DirectedEdge[a_, b_] :> 
      Directive[Arrowheads[Small], Lighter[colors[θ, x][a]], Thin]}, 
    VertexStyle -> {v_ :> colors[θ, x][v]}, 
    VertexCoordinates -> Join[Thread[Range[Length@hexlattice] -> hexlattice], 
     Thread[Length[hexlattice] + Range[Length@hexlattice] -> 
        (RotationTransform[θ, x] /@ hexlattice)]], 
    PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
    GridLines -> (List /@ x)], 
  {{θ, Pi/2}, 0, 2 Pi, Experimental`AngularSlider[##] &}, 
  {{x, {-2, -3}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: That angular slider is awesome. I'm going to get some use out of that!

Comment: @MassDefect, you might find ``NotebookTools`AngularSliderTest[]`` useful.

Answer (score 2):

My take.

```
rotate = RotationTransform[Pi/12, {2.5, 1}];

Show[
ListPlot[hexlattice], 
ListPlot[rotate /@ hexlattice], 
 Epilog -> ({Dashed, Blue, Opacity[0.6], Arrowheads[Small], 
      Arrow[#]} & /@ 
    Transpose[{Flatten[hexlattice, 1], 
      Flatten[rotate /@ hexlattice, 1]}]), 
PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, define the axis and the angle, then translate all points so that the origin is now your axis. After that rotate using the rotation matrix and put the origin back as it was. This can be summed up as

$$
\vec{x}_{new} = R(\theta) \cdot (\vec{x}_{old} - \vec{x}_{axis}) + \vec{x}_{axis}
$$

```
axis = {1, 1};
angle = π/20;
rotatedhexlattice = 
 Table[RotationMatrix[angle].(point - axis) + axis, {point,Flatten[hexlattice, 1]}]
```

Note, that I used `Flatten` because of the structure of `hexlattice`.

This produces the following listplot:

[image: rotated-hex]

Gray points are the old ones, orange "x" is the center and red points are the rotated ones.

Comment: If I use pts[a,b] with a>b or b>a. The lattice become deformated, you know why?